# Overriding a html5 viewport

Tags: android, html, scale, meta-tags, viewport

I build a simple android WebView for getting a html5-website. This website also provides the following line, which seems to always scale the view wrong (on my low density device):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

Unluckily all my attempts to scale the view down to 75% were unsuccessful,
which I tried by using various combinations of:

```
getView().getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); // used true, false
getView().getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); // used true, false
getView().getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // used true, false
getView().setInitialScale(0); // used 0, 75, 100, 150 here
```

Is there any other way of overriding the html5  ?

Regs,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax requires commas.
so simply replace the semi-colons (;) with commas (,) and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If possible remove the given meta tag from the html5-website.
Without the tag the page is zoomed to view the whole website.